# Show that hyperbolic space is differentiable manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

The hyperbolic space $H^n$, is defined as follows. Consider in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ a hyperboloid $H$ given by the equation  $$(x^{n+1})^2-(x')^2=1,$$  where $x'=(x^1,\ldots,x^n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x^{n+1}>0$. Show that $H^n$ is a differentiable manifold.

My approach: Obviosuly, we can prove this is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Let $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ a smooth manifold and $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ a smooth funciont on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ define as $f(x)=(x^{n+1})^2-(x')^2-1$, then if we consider the null set of this function $H^n=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}: f(x)=0\}$ we can see that $df\neq0$ on $H^n$, so $H^n$ is a submanifold of dimension $n$.

But how can I show that, this space $H^n$ is a differentiable manifold, using charts?

Comment: It's a graph. Any graph is a submanifold.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But, how can I show that this is a differentiable manifold using local charts?

Comment: You only need one chart for a graph.

Comment: The chart for the graph of $y=f(x)$ is $x \mapsto (x,f(x))$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but do you know another way to define a chart directly on this space? Something similar to defining the stereographic projection on the sphere...

Comment: Why do you need another way?

Comment: Only for curiosity. I have never seen the construction by chart of this space $H^n$

Comment: "...similar to defining stereographic projection on the sphere" doesn't have much meaning. Stereographic projection is a particular chart defined on a particular space (the sphere), so if you want something "similar" for $H^n$ then you'll have to tell us what particular properties of stereographic projection you wish to see reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

The chart is $x\to x^\prime.$ You don't need stereographic projection.